# CoroutineScope extension function in a different class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use an extension function to `CoroutineScope` to launch some asynchronous work.
I'm not sure how to call this method from my main class, see below:

```kotlin
class MyService {
   fun CoroutineScope.getFoo() = async(IO|Single|Default) { ... }
}

class MyProgram(val service : MyService) : CoroutineScope {
   fun main() {
      launch {
         // Doesn't work, unresloved `service.getFoo`.
         val deferred = service.getFoo() getFoo

         // Works, but looks a bit odd IMO.
         val deferred = with(service) { getFoo() }

         deferred.await()
      }  
   }
}
```

I know I could just move the `async {}` keyword to my main method, but in this way, the caller would have to decide the scheduler.
The service knows the nature of its work (IO/Computation bound single-threaded?, etc) and I think it should be the one deciding the scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your intent is to let the service specify the scheduler. Why not split the specification of the scheduler and the decision to run asynchronously?

Let the service function be suspendable and use `withContext` to specify the scheduler.
And let the caller decide, if the function should run asynchronously.

```
class MyService {
    suspend fun getFoo() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //work 
    }
}

abstract class MyProgram(val service: MyService) : CoroutineScope {

    fun main() {
        launch {
            val deferred = async { service.getFoo() }

            //some work

            deferred.await()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach, it has some benefits: 1. It leaves it up to the caller decide to suspend and not run this work asynchronously for whatever reason 2. The `async` and `await` keywords are in the same parent coroutine and the fact that `service.getFoo` returns a deferred doesn't come as a surprise 3. My method signatures are not polluted with coroutine-specific objects

Answer (score 1):

Why not make `getFoo` a normal function and pass in the scope:

```
fun getFoo(scope: CoroutineScope) = scope.async {
    //work }
}

launch {
    service.getFoo(this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's definitely better than this `val deferred = with(service) { getFoo() }`, I don't like the idea of having to pass around the scope all the time but I'll stick to it if I can't find a better way.